# SwiftyStoreKit - presentCodeRedemptionSheet() method for offer codes not available ios

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I have read about offer codes introduced by Apple to show discounts to the active subscription users. But I am not able to find any working demo for it. Has anyone implemented it?

presentCodeRedemptionSheet() presents the screens but it does not show the done button after entering the promo code.

Comment: Hi Nisha, stackoverflow works best when you have a particular problem with reproducible code. As it stands, this question is too broad

Comment: @nisha did you find the solution?

Comment: @vishnuhari not yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [presentCodeRedemptionSheet not showing Redeem offer button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274113/presentcoderedemptionsheet-not-showing-redeem-offer-button)

Answer (score 1):

Press the "return" button on the keyboard and you are good to go.