# presentCodeRedemptionSheet not showing Redeem offer button

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swift5, in-app-subscription

I create offer codes on my iTunes account in my monthly subscription.
I am using **presentCodeRedemptionSheet** StoreKit API to enter redeem code within the app using this
code

```
 let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        paymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
    }
```

The above code presenting me this UI

[image]

after entering the code this UI not showing me **redeem offer button**.

[image]

I am stuck here please help me :) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the keyboard tap `Return` button on the bottom-right corner, not the `Done` button on the top-right.

Comment: Best UI ever :P

Comment: why does it not show your icon app @balkaran sigh